# How do I set Item Level permission on an Issue List in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a Sharepoint Issue List in which I need users to

- Read All Items
- But Edit Items created by them.

In Sharepoint normal List, We can do so by Advanced Settings -> Item Level Permission. This option is not available in Issue List.

I have even tried with the below Code:

```
      SPList list = web.Lists["Shared Documents"]; 
      list.ReadSecurity = 2; 
      list.WriteSecurity = 2; 
      list.Update();
```

Can anyone suggest what else can be done?